next.js app routing - navigate to page but rerender component without remounting
I have components like this:
<Layout>
  <Page>
    <Component/>
  </Page>
</Layout>

when a user navigates between pages, the Component is remounted, even though it's the same Page.
If I change it to:
<Layout>
  <Page/>
  <Component/>
</Layout>

then when a user navigates between pages, using Link, the Component never re-renders.
Layout and Page are server components and Component is a client component.  the parent of Component is dynamically rendered as it needs headers and params.
I did try a static key with <Page><Component key/></Page> but Component still remounted.  I can't put a key on <Page> because that's part of Next.js and Layout receives {children} with <Page/>
How can I get Component to re-render without re-mounting?

I did it this way:
<Layout>
  <Page/>
  <Component/>
</Layout>

Layout doesn't re-render, but I added usePathname to Component so it re-renders without remounting.
